# Apache using wrong Python version, 2.4 script working, 2.5 script failing

Tags: apache-2.2, python

Using CentOS5, I have Apache configured with the following directives.

```
Alias /pscript/ /var/www/pscript/
<Directory "/var/www/pscript/">
    Options +ExecCGI
    DirectoryIndex thetest.py
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

When I call www.domain.com/pscript/ then my python script runs and prints out my `sys.path`, which is displaying `python2.4`.

When I call a different script that requires Python 2.5, I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Looking at my Apache error_log, I see the following line:

```
[Wed Mar 03 16:58:44 2010] [error] [client 000.000.000.000] Please use Python 2.5 or greater
```

From the command line, running `python -V` returns `Python 2.5.5`. I have both 2.4 and 2.5.5 installed, but only 2.5.5 should be in use.

In an attempt to remedy the Apache problem I recompiled Python 2.5.5 to be safe, and made sure to enable shared library. Then I recompiled mod_python in case that was affecting something, but my `sys.path` is still `python2.4`.

I wonder, do I need to recompile Apache 2.2.3 itself? I simply need Apache to utilize Python 2.5.5.

Edit: It appears both of my python installations have shared libraries. Obviously the 2.4 version predates 2.5. Would this be a possible cause?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found a solution for this?
I'm facing this same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within my python script /usr/bin/env was being used to call Python. This was calling the wrong version. Not sure how to make it call a different version, but changing my scripts to /usr/bin/local/python (Python 2.5.5 installation) corrected the problem.

Comment: You'd set/adjust the sys.path environment variable (for the user the script runs as) to pick up your desired Python version.

Alternatively, you could take a look at virtualenv.

Comment: Is there a preferred way to modify `sys.path` to accomplish this? I will also look into virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

The apache process is most likely running as a different user and might be picking up a different system path to your own user.

Perhaps, assuming your apache user is www-data, running the following command will confirm it:

```
sudo su www-data python -V
```

Comment: The user is different, I confirmed the one that was declared in the httpd.conf file. Using "su" to login as that user, I ran "python -V" and it printed "Python 2.5.5"